# What to change to prevent double request from service worker?

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, next.js, fetch-api

Please do not mark as duplicate. This is not an exact duplicate of the other similar questions here on SO. It's more specific and fully reproducible.

1. Clone [this](https://github.com/zen-testt/next_sw_test) repo.
2. `yarn && yarn dev`
3. Go to `localhost:3000` and make sure under (F12)->Applications->Service workers, the service worker is installed.
4. Go to Network tab and refresh a few times(F5)
5. Observe how the network requests are doubled.

Example of what I see:
[image]

---

Or if you want to do it manually follow the instructions below:

1. `yarn create-next-app app_name`
2. `cd app_name && yarn`
3. in public folder, create file called `service-worker.js` and paste the following code:

```
addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  self.skipWaiting();
  console.log("Service worker installed!");
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  event.respondWith(
    (async function () {
      const promiseChain = fetch(event.request.clone()); // clone makes no difference
      event.waitUntil(promiseChain); // makes no difference
      return promiseChain;
    })()
  );
});
```

4. open `pages/index.js` and just below `import Head from "next/head";` paste the following code:

```
if (typeof window !== "undefined" && "serviceWorker" in navigator) {
  window.addEventListener("load", function () {
    // there probably needs to be some check if sw is already registered
    navigator.serviceWorker
      .register("/service-worker.js", { scope: "/" })
      .then(function (registration) {
        console.log("SW registered: ", registration);
      })
      .catch(function (registrationError) {
        console.log("SW registration failed: ", registrationError);
      });
  });
}
```

5. `yarn dev`
6. go to `localhost:3000` and make sure the service worker has been loaded under (F12)Applications/Service Workers
7. Go to the Network tab and refresh the page a few times. See how the service worker sends two requests for each one

---

What do I need to change in the `service-worker.js` code so that there are no double requests?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is how Chrome DevTools shows requests and is expected.

There is a request for a resource from the client JavaScript to the Service Worker and a request from the Service Worker to the server. This will always happen unless the service worker has the response cached and does not need to check the server for an update.

Comment: This is true, but it doesn't explain why the server registers 2 requests. I have noticed that sometimes an additional request is sent to the server with the same payload.

Comment: The question was about devtools logs not server logs. They will show different things. Duplicate server logs often is a request that is rendered followed by the service worker installing and making a second request that is cached.

Comment: @ACEGL I have tested this in my app and the requests shown as double in the DevTools are NOT actually sent two times to the server, but only once. Are you sure you observed a different thing?

Comment: Depending on how a Service Worker is configured, on initial registration there might be a network request for the resource to render the page and a duplicate network request to pre-cache the resource by the SW.

Answer (score 0):

Does not seems the right way to initialize service worker in Next.js.You may need to look into [next-pwa](https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa#readme) plugin to do it right.Here is the tutorial [PWA with Next.js](https://itnext.io/pwa-with-next-js-create-next-app-in-2020-%EF%B8%8F-9ee0e1a6313d)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by right? It doesn't make much sense to me. I know the PWA section but that's a big overkill for the project's purpose. Which is to simply intercept the request. These packages are not necessary, they are just helpers for caching, which the project does not require.

Comment: The out of the box developer experience when working with Next.js is very slick, with hot code reloading, automatic server restarts and transpilation using Babel built in by default.
Unfortunately the default setup doesn’t allow us an easy way to scope the service worker to our root path so a custom server implementation is needed.    https://medium.com/@anatomic/using-a-service-worker-with-next-js-460e0168a60a

Answer (score 0):

**If anyone is looking for an answer to the original question 'What to change to prevent double request from service worker?', specifically for network requests.**

I've found a way to prevent it. Use the following in the serviceworker.js. (This also works for api calls etc.)

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', async function(event) {

    await new Promise(function(res){setTimeout(function(){res("fetch request allowed")}, 9999)})
    return false

});
```

Comment: It should be noted this basically removes the service worker's functionality. But in my case this was exactly what I needed since I only had one so that Chrome would recognize my site as a PWA.