# Legacy PWA - GTM loads twice

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, google-tag-manager

I set up PWA on older response-request application (jQuery, php).
Manifest file and service worker are ok.
The app is on Google Play - thats why I set it up.

The problem is GTM, which runs sometimes twice. I can see it in Chrome in Tag Assistant plug as well as in DevTools - Network section (see attached image).

Website: https://eshop.sklizeno.cz

Where is the problem? How to get rid of it?

two gtm loads

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that I will answer to myself.

I installed Chrome plugin called Network Sniffer, which shows real traffic and there is no double request there.

Related topic with confirmation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61210323/14447830

I would be glad if somebody confirms, that I am right.

[ChromeDevTools request vs. real requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwgmF.png)

Comment: Thanks, good to know that it's not double loading.  Too bad the network tab is a little misleading in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend adding more files to your cache.  Then make sure you change your cache name when you make updates.

I ran your PWA.  I couple things stood out.

1. You're only caching a few font and image files in your service worker.  I'd look at caching most of your files.

[image]

2. Next, then looked at the Chrome Network tab, I see that every file has 2 entries in the table, except for the files in your cache, they just show (ServiceWorker), not a 2nd row for (disk cache).

Keep adding files to your cache, until nearly everything just comes from "ServiceWorker" only (not "disk cache").

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer.
1) Good advice, I know about that, but its not directly connected with the issue :-)
2) Good point, I think the solution might be to put GTM into separete .js file and cache it with service worker. I will try it.

Comment: What I tried did not helped at all. Problem was the same.